# Symfony form basedon database field

Tags: php, symfony1

I want to build a form in Symfony 1.2:

```
$this->form = new CmsPageItemForm(Doctrine::getTable('CmsPageItem')->find('blah'));
```

except I want to show only rows based on a a field in the database that is not the primary key:

```
$this->form = new CmsPageItemForm(Doctrine::getTable('CmsPageItem')->findByCmsPageId(1));
```

can this be done? I don't get why this is so difficult in Symfony.

```
mysql> select * From cms_page_item;
+------------------+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------------+------------+------------+
| cms_page_item_id | cms_page_id | cms_page_item_title | cms_page_text_desc            | created_at | updated_at |
+------------------+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------------+------------+------------+
|                1 |           1 | como                | blah blah                     | NULL       | NULL       |
|                2 |           1 | quien               | rah rah rah                   | NULL       | NULL       |
|                3 |           1 | hey                 | kjhszkhks slasflv aslkdhaslk  | NULL       | NULL       |
+------------------+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: `Symfony 1.2` or `Symfony 2.1`? I ask because of the `Symfony2` tag...

Comment: symfony 1.2 - ah whoops